# 'Random' returning value that's not in array?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm very new to Java and am writing a method that randomly selects an element from a 2 dimensional array.

The idea is that you give it a 2 dimensional array of 52 cards (13 cards in 4 suites) and you randomly select 4 of them and return their total sum.

The program seems to work fine for the most part but sometimes it will return the card "0 of diamonds". This is not an element in the array I gave the method so not quite sure whats going on here.

I'll reproduce most of the relevant code below:

```
    int [][] cards = {{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},
            {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14},{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14}};
    int num1 = randomPick(cards);
        sum = sum+num1; 

    switch(num1){
        case 11: System.out.print("Jack of "+ suite+", ");
            break;
        case 12: System.out.print("Queen of "+ suite+", ");
            break;
        case 13: System.out.print("King of "+ suite+", ");
            break;
        case 14: System.out.print("Ace of "+ suite+", ");
            break;
        default: System.out.print(num1+" of "+ suite+", ");
            break;}


    public static int randomPick(int[][] array){                        
    int randrow = new Random().nextInt(array.length);               
    int randcol = new Random().nextInt(array[randrow].length);      
    switch (randrow){
    // Each row corresponds to a different suite of cards
    case 1:
        suite= "spades";
        break;
    case 2:
        suite = "hearts";
        break;
    case 3:
        suite = "diamonds";
        break;
    case 0:
        suite = "clubs";
        break;
    }       
    int element =array[randrow][randcol];
    return(element);}
```

As you can see 0 is an not an element in the array that was passed to the method, how is it sometimes returning 0?

Comment: Some of your example code is missing - what you've pasted can't compile. If you share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) we can run your code directly and try to replicate the issue.

Comment: Cards have a "suit", not a "suite".

Answer (score 1):

The above implementation of `randomPick` would not return `0` if the same `cards` array is passed to it in every call.

It looks like `cards` array gets modified somewhere down the line and `randomPick` gets called with updated array? I would recommend adding a logging or `sysout` in `randomPick` method if the `element` is 0, e.g.:

```
int element =array[randrow][randcol];
if(element == 0){
    for(int[] arrayElement : array){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayElement));
    }
}
```